# How to manage session between cakephp version 2.x and android for subsequent call using retrofit2

Tags: retrofit2

```
    @GET("product/allProduct.json;cakephp={session_key}")
    Call<Product> getProductData(@Path("cakephp") String session_Key);

 Call<Product> call=apiInterface.getAssetsData(session_key);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
                Log.d("TAG","success"+new Gson().toJson(response.body()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponseFail ");
            }
        });
```

I am getting response null from above code,please provide some inputs if i am missing anything.